# Download file from php server with vuejs

Tags: vue.js, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

My application is running on CakePHP with vuejs as front end js framework.

I am making an axios request to server for generating the output file and file is generated in webroot folder of cakephp.

```
Api()
.get('/articles/downloadFile')
.then(response => {
});
```

How can I download the generated file through vuejs?

Comment: You can do it using `window.open('/articles/downloadFile')`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to pass `responseType` as `blob` in the `axios` call. Something like this

```
.get('/articles/downloadFile', {responseType: 'blob'})
```

And then, in when the promise resolves to generate a `href` element in the DOM and download the item.

```
.then((response) => {
    const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response.data]));
    const link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = url;
    link.setAttribute('download', 'image.png');
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
})
```

I'm assuming that you are downloading an image, you need to change the name and the extension for your use case.

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c9qw4tdu/15/) with a complete example.

NB: for this to work (even just the GET call) your CORS policy must allow this call.

Comment: I am returning a csv file from server. And my cakephp server can only return JSON response.